# Wordpress Config file 403 Error - How?

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I have a quick question that's driving me insane and would appreciate the assistance.

On a live wordpress setup, how does accessing /wp-config.php from a browser result in a 403 error when you can access all other PHP files fine froma webbrowser? The config.php file has a chmod that permits public read AND there's no mention of it in the corresponding .htaccess.

Just very curious as to how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Could be a dozen of different reasons. No way for us to tell from here.

Comment: It works with `.htaccess` rules , and if it not there then the rules are specified elsewhere in a directory above or server wide configuration.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just confirmed that access to all files by the name of wp-config.php have been 403'ed through Apache at the server level.
Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is server specific, but you could definitely add a rule to the web server configuration to do this. For instance, using Apache, you could do something similar to this:

```
<Directory /var/web/dir1>
    <Files private.html>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

My point here is that there are more ways to configure permissions for files served by a web server than file system permissions.

It should also be noted that if you are not the administrator of the machine running the web server, you may not have access to tweak these settings.

Comment: Just confirmed that access to all files by the name of wp-config.php have been 403'ed through Apache at the server level.
Cheers for the help!